# Ubuntu 18.04 Lockscreen maximum size?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, display-resolution, lock-screen, desktop-background

I was trying to change my lockscreen wallpaper because the inbuilt feature didn't work. I searched and found a solution of this. Edit line 1814 in

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/alternatives/gdm3.css
```

to

```
#lockDialogGroup {
  background: #2c001e url(file://{file location});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; }
```

This works, but not in every situation. I have 2 `.jpg` files file 1 is 108.5kB and file 2 is 9.5kB, both located in the same directory. With file 1, the lockscreen changes when I log out after logging in(turn on -> login(Isn't changed) -> log out(it's changed)). With file 2, both works fine.
So the question is
1. Is there a maximum file size limit or a maximum resolution for the lockscreen.(file 1 works fine for normal wallpaper)
2. What is the solution for this? Is there a way to scale the image like `object-fit` in css?

ps. The file I want to use is file 1. I tested file 2 to check if the method is valid.

Comment: I spent a half hour searching and couldn't find anything. Perhaps open `file1.jpg` in gimp (or another image editor / converter) and export it as `file1.png` to see if that works better?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix After reading your comment I converted the file to ```.png``` and know it works. Thank you! But why is this happening? I think it's because some body who uploaded the image changed the original png file to jpg. But its a little awkward because in windows everything worked fine even if I changed from jpg to png and vice versa.

Comment: I posted an answer showing how the problem was solved. As a new user please be advised you need to click the grey check mark next to the answer so others know the solution. As for how and why the problem happened I put that into the answer but it is only a guess as we can't see the actual file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, converting `.jpg` to a `.png` file fixed the issue.

`.png` is a more native file format for Linux and `.jpg` is a more native file format for Windows. That said the file conversion software may have removed "noise" from the `.jpg` file when converting it to `.png` format. If there was "noise" what it was is anyone's guess. If you are in a similar situation and you must have `.jpg` file format you can still convert it to another `.jpg` file with a bit of file compression and may also be successful.